# How to update a field of another model in a pre_save function?

Tags: python, django, model, save, signals

I have a model called SPL, which gets new objects in a fixed interval. Every time it gets a new object, the function "process_data" gets called by the pre_save signal. 
In this function, I am trying to update the field "leq_start" in another model "Index" based on the field "time" of the SPL model object. The Code seems to work because I don't get any error, but the field does not get updated. What's wrong?
I have some other functions based on a post_save signal where it works fine...

I've already tried the update alternative, but that didn't work either.

```
Index.objects.filter(device_id=id_).update(leq_start=instance.time)
```

```py
def process_data(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    id_ = instance.device_id
    num = instance.number
    # new code
    prevNum = Index.objects.get(device_id=id_).previous_nbr
    dP = num - prevNum
    if dP > 0:
        if prevNum == 0: 
            dT = 60
            b = Index.objects.get(device_id=id_)
            b.leq_start = instance.time
            b.save()
            instance.leq_60=instance.leq
            return
        else:
                ...

pre_save.connect(process_data, sender=SPL)
```

Comment: Well, presumably one of those if conditions is false. Note that this could be massively simplified by referring to `instance.device` directly rather than getting the ID and requerying each time.

Comment: Seems like it's not a problem with the if condition. All the other statements, especially the one after b.save() habe been executed...